# How do I suppress this output?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a code chunk in an R Markdown file.

````
```{r}
library(UsingR)
```
````

Using knitHTML to compile causes the following output, which never happened before I updated to the latest versions of R and RStudio:

```
## Loading required package: MASS
## Loading required package: HistData
## Loading required package: Hmisc
## Loading required package: grid
## Loading required package: lattice
## Loading required package: survival
## Loading required package: splines
## Loading required package: Formula
## 
## Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
## 
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     format.pval, round.POSIXt, trunc.POSIXt, units
## 
## Loading required package: aplpack
## Loading required package: tcltk
## Loading required package: quantreg
## Loading required package: SparseM
## 
## Attaching package: 'SparseM'
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     backsolve
## 
## 
## Attaching package: 'quantreg'
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:Hmisc':
## 
##     latex
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:survival':
## 
##     untangle.specials
## 
## 
## Attaching package: 'UsingR'
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:survival':
## 
##     cancer
```

How can I suppress this output? Note: echo=FALSE did not work.

Comment: did you try `?suppressPackageStartupMessages`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `message=FALSE` in your code chunk should work.

````
```{r, message=FALSE}
library(UsingR)
```
````

Setting `echo=FALSE` should not have worked - this is by design. The `echo` parameter in the code chunk controls the display of the code inside the chunk (i.e. `library(UsingR)`).

Messages (as shown) are handled separately through the `message` parameter.

Errors are handled through the `error` parameter (i.e. `error=FALSE` will suppress error messages).

Results are handled through the `results` parameter (i.e. `results=FALSE` will suppress the results of the code chunk).

Warnings are handled through the `warning` parameter (i.e. `warning=FALSE` will suppress the warnings generated by the code chunk) as warnings are distinct from errors.

There are many other code-chunk parameters available, but these are the main parameters governing the text-based output generated by a given code-chunk.

Comment: How does one do this with roxygen2 mark up in an R script for notebook generation?