# how do I suppress the message of a function in an R script?

Tags: r, rscript

A similar question was asked previously at:

[How do I suppress this output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466774/how-do-i-suppress-this-output)

However, that question is only applicable to Rmarkdown code blocks. In the following case I've created a script with only the following:

```
library(UsingR)
```

I've saved the file this time as an Rscript named `test.R`. However, I am using the Compile Notebook icon to compile to an html document. The resulting output is as shown:

[image]

In the previous question on the link given above, the answer was:

````
```{r message=FALSE}
library(UsingR)
```
````

which will only work in an Rmarkdown code block.

How do I suppress messages of functions more generally, for example the output of the `library()` function?

Comment: No. The first occurred in an RMarkdown file compiled using knitHTML. This one occurred in an R script, clicking the Compile Notebook icon in RStudio. Similar, but different.

Comment: Irrelevant.  It is about suppressing output from `library() ` and that question has been answered several times.

Comment: Are we relitigating _seven year old_ answers?  Didn't anything else worth arguing happen in the meantime?

Comment: (sorry for deleting my comment) I realise now what you meant. Though I do think this question is different enough to remove the duplicate flag. I only bring it up because the question, and answer provided are relevant to my current situation, whereas the linked QnA is not. I'm just trying to be helpful. -- I also realise this has been answered in other places, but I think the answer here is correct, and the same answer for other questions is less relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the call to `library` so that it doesn't print any output:

```
library(UsingR, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```

More generally, you can suppress messages from an expression by wrapping it in a `suppressMessages`:

```
suppressMessages(expr)
```

Comment: library(UsingR,quietly=TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE) did not work. Got the same output. suppressMessages(library(UsingR)) worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan this is super useful, thanks.  In particular I had a function that needs to be called thousands of time and each time would print a redundant message() that could jam up the console.